# Did Ali say that only Muhammad's descendants can rule?

Tags: islam

[Islam stackexchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/58263/did-ali-ever-say-that-only-house-of-muhamad-can-rule-muslims/58318?noredirect=1#comment96147_58318) wasn't able to answer this question. It quotes [Wikipedia:Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali).

This is a politically charged question I think.

Sunnis and Shias see Ali positively. So if there are Sunni records that say even Ali think that way, it'll be something.

So are there any historical sources or biographies or hadith that say that?

Comment: Hereditary succession was a thing that goes way back in quite a few forms... Why would you expect Muhammad or any of his descendants to make it more explicit than other hereditary monarchs (or other)?

Comment: I have no idea. I will need some direct quotations and so on to know it. The first 4 calpihs of islams are "elected". It's a move toward meritocracy and democracy but not far and they went back to hereditary monarchs. What's the actual story?

Comment: No idea what the actual story is in the case of the Caliphs, but FWIW in the case France, monarchs were initially elected, until one family became dominant, at which point they got "elected" as a matter of course, and ultimately the elections just went away.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy England similarly.  The first post-conquest succession by primogeniture was not until 1189, and pre-conquest hereditary succession was also often not observed.

Comment: Just to add to those two examples, it's worth stressing that Europe was quite different from Eastern empires in this respect. "Divine" rulers were ubiquitous further East. So it may very well have been that, in contrast with Europe during the same time period, hereditary rule would have been seen as a matter of course in Arab controlled lands at the time.

Comment: Not sure why you say [Islam.se] wasn't able to answer. There are two answers there, although one is, admittedly short.

Comment: One of the answer is bad. Another is interesting and looks correct. However, some would say it's too pro syiah. I would check that one as answer.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy simply speaking Ali was by no means a descendant or (a direct) inheritor of Muhammed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [my answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/59463/4058) on Islam.SE, if you think non-Muslim sources may be less "biased" (I agree many Muslim sources can be biased on this, even though I believe the Shia view is accurate), you may want to [read](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2QKBUwBUWWkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) the [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Succession_to_Muhammad) by Wilfred Madelung, a German-British scholar of early Islamic history who has confirmed the idea of superiority of Ali over the caliphs and his disputes with them.

Note that even Western scholars are divided on this to some part. Madelung's work though is among the most recent works which builds up on previous scholarship but also criticizes them, giving qualified support to the Shia belief. But he diverges from the Shia view that the Prophet Muhammad had actually appointed Ali as his caliph but he argues that hereditary succession was always a given in Abrahamic traditions as well as Quranic account of succession to past prophets.

PS: In reference to comments, the idea that the first three caliphs were "elected" is also contested. If the electoral excludes some of the most prominent companions of the Prophet and involves coercion, it can't be called an "election" and this was the case for Saqifa the first "election" which was more like a factional coup d'état. The second caliph was also appointed not elected. You may want to post a separate question on this but you can also consult Madelung's comprehensive account of post-prophetic politics.

Comment: +1. One small quibble regarding your PS about those elections not being proper elections, if I may. I'd suggest reading up on what elections looked like before the 20th century. Or for that matter, nowadays, in an alarming number of countries ([including](https://www.ted.com/talks/lawrence_lessig_we_the_people_and_the_republic_we_must_reclaim?language=en) [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering_in_the_United_States) [US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_suppression)). :D

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Thanks for links. Yes, I am familiar with Gerrymandering and some other criticisms against modern democracies.

Comment: The thing with "proper" election is it's often not clear who should "elect". I can say that my bro elect me and we got "consensus". The fact that Ali wasn't there makes me wonder why he isn't qualify to "elect" but people probably don't notice those minor details

Comment: *hereditary succession was always a given in Abrahamic traditions* - When it comes to Patriarchs or Kings, yes, but not when it comes to Prophets (proper); e.g., Joshua was not related to Moses, Elisha was not a descendant of Elijah, nor Baruch of Jeremiah, etc.

Comment: @Lucian Hereditary succession doesn't have to be through son. In the Quran Moses asked to have a caliph or representative from his family and Aaron his brother was determined by Allah to be his caliph. Solomon succeeded his father David, both prophets according to Islam. Ali was the Prophet's cousin, son-in-law and spiritual brother.

Comment: @infatuated: In the Bible, Aaron died before Moses. Joshua, who succeeded Moses (and Aaron), was not from their lineage. Same with other biblical prophets.

Comment: @Lucian But that would be still consistent with the Quran that says Aaron represented Moses during his life. The word used in the Quran is "khilapha" or caliphate which means "deputy".

Comment: @infatuated: Correct, the Qur'an seems to have Exodus 4:14-17 in mind. Nevertheless, their successor was a man unrelated to either. (And at least several other similarly relevant examples can be produced).

Comment: @Lucian But Aaron died earlier than Moses otherwise he had most probably succeeded him, right?